# Why is a path to a .so library in my executable on Ubuntu 14.04 but not 18.04?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, shared-libraries

I've put together a simple "build" and "install" process for a set of tools I've inherited in a new job. The build is a simple set of makefiles that will build each tool and put the binary in a shared "bin" folder. The "install" copies all of the bins, scripts, and libraries this set of tools needs to "/usr/bin/toolsuite". When I need to update the code I simply delete the old toolsuite folder and "install" a new one. This way any library updates, code changes, etc. All can be handled the same way.

I would like this process to work in both Ubuntu 18.04 and Ubuntu 14.04, as there are machines that use this code that can't be migrated away from 14.04 at this time (for reasons that are not directly related to the tool suite I'm discussing here). Unfortunately 14.04 seems to be linking to a proprietary library file differently than 18.04 and I have no idea how to go about debugging.

My repo includes a dozen or so very simple c applications that each have a makefile (many of them link to the library). All the makefiles are identical except for the specifics at the top of the file. Here is an example:

```
##########################################
#           Editable options             #
##########################################

# Folders
LIBFOLDER=../../lib
INCLUDEFOLDER=../../include
BINFOLDER=../../bin
OBJFOLDER=../../objs

# Compiler options
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-ggdb -Wall -c -I$(INCLUDEFOLDER)/tpapi -I$(INCLUDEFOLDER)
LDFLAGS=-L$(LIBFOLDER)/xxxlib -Wl,--enable-new-dtags,-rpath=/usr/bin/tool-suite/lib
LDLIBS=-l:xxxlib64.so -lrt -lpthread
EXECUTABLE_NAME=application_1

# Files
SOURCES=application_1.c

#########################################################
# Do not replace #
#########################################################
EXECUTABLES = $(EXECUTABLE_NAME:%=$(BINFOLDER)/%)
OBJECTS     = $(SOURCES:%.c=$(OBJFOLDER)/%.o)

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLES)

$(EXECUTABLES): $(OBJECTS)
    @echo Building $<
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)
    @echo "Build successful!"

$(OBJECTS): $(OBJFOLDER)/%.o: %.c
    @echo Compiling $<
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    python3 ../../scripts/build_ops.py set-version
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

.PHONY : clean
clean :
    -rm $(EXECUTABLES) $(OBJECTS)
```

In 18.04 when I run

```
readelf -d application_1
```

Things look as expected, xxlib64.so is marked as a dependency and absolute path the application can find it is in my rpath:

```
Dynamic section at offset 0x3cb8 contains 31 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [xxxlib64.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [librt.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH)            Library runpath: [/usr/bin/tool-suite/lib]
```

But on 14.04 (using the exact same git commit, and exact same makefiles) I see this:

```
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [../../lib/xxxlib/xxxlib64.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [librt.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH)            Library runpath: [/usr/bin/tool-suite/lib]
```

The xxxlib64.so entry in 14.04 includes the full relative path of where it was found at build time. And for the life of me I can't figure out why. The 14.04 systems were configured by a different engineer before my time so it is possible they have some odd configuration. But I don't know what to look for as far as weird configurations go.

I tried installing gcc-7 from the ubuntu "ToolChain" ppa and using the same version of gcc as 18.04. It did not result in any change.

There are no errors during compile on 14.04 nothing to indicate that anything is wrong. But when the application tries to run it specifically tries to find ../../xxlib64.so instead of xxlib64.so which isn't ever going to work and fails at runtime.

Does anyone have any advice on how I would go about debugging why 14.04 is using that full relative path? Or how I might go about "post-processing" the binary files in 14.04 to change that path to not be relative?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with this form of `-l` option: `-l:xxxlib64.so`.  Specifically, it's the colon that's throwing me.  I don't find it described in GCC's documentation, either.  Additionally, I don't know that it matters, but why use a non-standard library name (xxxlib64 instead of libxxx64)?  At minimum, it makes your link options uglier, and I see no advantage whatever.  Usually, shared object names that don't start with "lib" are reserved for dynamically-loaded objects.

Comment: @John - `-l:xxxlib64.so` is a [`ld(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld) linker option. It effectively says, "use this exact filename when linking". Search for *`:filename`* in the `ld(1)` man page. I usually use it for static archives when needed, like `-l:xxxlib64.a`, because shared object linking is the default.

Comment: @Josh - Forgive my ignorance... You don't provide details of *"due to some software compatibility issues"*. What is the problem you are experiencing? Or what is the question? (You should also remove a lot of the unneeded commentary. It is just distracting).

Comment: Thanks, @jww, I learned something new today.  In any case, since the OP knows the exact location of this object, it may be worthwhile to try directly naming it as an object to link instead of using an `-l` option.  And if an `-l` option is to be used, then naming the library in the conventional way so as to avoid using the `:` form would also be something worth trying.  I'm working from the premise that the behavior on 14.04 is buggy, and that looks like the best crevice to hide such a bug.

Comment: @John - I'm not sure what - exactly - the problem is here. What is the issue trying to be fixed? Does OP just want dynamic linking to `xxxlib64.so`? Is he encountering *`undefined reference to ...`*? If so, we need to see a directory listing and the makefile that builds it. It could be the case only `xxxlib64.a` exists. Or, a symlink may be missing. Until he states what the exact problem is, we can only speculate.

Comment: Also, one thing about Ubuntu is, it adds linker paths without telling anyone. I believe Ubuntu uses `/usr/local/lib` by default. He may be picking up `xxxlib64.a` in `/usr/local/lib` so `<some dir>/xxxlib64.so` is never considered. We would probably need to see `-v` output from compile and link to see search paths.

Comment: @jww, the problem is that on 14.04, the library SONAME is recorded in a `DTNEEDED` entry in the main program as `../../lib/xxxlib/xxxlib64.so`, whereas the expected behavior, which is observed on 18.04, is that the SONAME recorded in the main program is just `xxxlib64.so`.  This presents a runtime problem, for reasons I'm sure you appreciate.

Comment: The library in question is from a group external to my own. They chose the name. I just have to deal with it using the weird -l option. I agree that it should have been named differently.

Comment: @jww i have edited to remove some of that and maybe give some more useful context. Thank you for the comment. The "compatibility issues" I referred to is a whole other much more convoluted topic that I'm trying to figure out seperately from all this. Right now I have to live in both 18.04 and 14.04. I will move everything to 18.04 when I can but it probably won't be for several months. And I'd like a consistent build in the mean time.

Comment: @John Bollinger has succinctly summarized my problem.

Comment: @John Bollinger:

Mentioned that maybe the "-l:" behavior was buggy in 14.04. I think I have substantiated that idea. For a test I've renamed the library to standard name "libxxx.so" and added it using -lxxx. It now appears in the readelf output without all the relative path info.

As I mentioned though this library is coming from an external group. Renaming it presents some problems. So I don't think this solves my issue. But it points me in the direction of what is actually wrong.

Which application would actually be doing this? LD? Having used gcc-7 I'm confident gcc isn't at fault.

Comment: The linker (ld) would presumably be the responsible component.  It should be part of the binutils package.  But again, since you have a path to the lib, it would be worth a shot to just specify it directly as an object to link, without using any form of `-l`.  You should get a successful link that way -- I'm just uncertain whether it will resolve the SONAME problem.

Comment: I'll give that a try tomorrow. But how will that work at runtime? Will rpath still be required? The location of the library I expect it to use at runtime is not the same as the one I expect it to use at build time.

Comment: Got pulled away from this project for a little while. Got back to it today. Linking the object directly did not fix the problem I need to include the folder path for the linker to find the .so file. And it puts that full path in the NEEDED entry. So the entry looks identical to the bad entry I see using the "-l:" option.

Comment: For the time being I'm gonna go with a solution I don't like. I've just made copies of the library files and given the copies standard names. When I have left 14.04 behind for good I can remove those copies. If anyone has any other suggestions though I'd still love a better solution than this.